# What is the entropy of the oscillating air column?

Tags: thermodynamics

Standing waves in woodwind  instruments vibrate with a fundamental  mode and  its harmonics . Those vibrations involve a large number of particles, /in a range of Avogadro number/, which vibrate in a phase locked mode . This is well organized , far from  random  movement,  in which its possible to determine with a high accuracy the  position and  momentum  of the groups of air molecules. Therefore the question is what would be the entropy of the  this  oscillating air column in the woodwind instruments oscillating with a fundamental frequency and numerous harmonics ?

Comment: What do you mean by "oscillating with a fundamental frequency and numerous harmonics"? Do you mean you are interested in any single mode, or more of a linear combination of modes?

Comment: I'm interested in a linear combination of modes which resembles  vibration in a real woodwind instruments.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also interested in the entropy description for the linear combination of modes. I suspect that the oscillation of the fundamental and its harmonics between coherence and decoherence accounts for a kind of "average entropy" over time. I have nothing except a visualization of the harmonic series to back this up though...